# is there any functions in google sheets to resolve the below problem?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to filter the value in F (F>100) and group values in F according to Values in E, find the total for the group and multiply it with value in B as per the group (ie, A,B,C etc.,) and the final totals of the multiplied values for all groups

sum(A)*20+sum(B)*30+sum(C)*15 and so on

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGPNN.png)

Comment: That should be possible. Can you share the example spreadsheet so we have some data to work with?

Comment: hi, please use this link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u2Eb3myB6EviRGtdc1OyfSRlDiYcz5SrFbWaIRNgSfs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=index(query({E:F, IFERROR(F:F*VLOOKUP(E:E, A:B, 2, 0))}, "Select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col2 > 100 group by Col1 label sum(Col3)''", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, it is close to what I need. but ultimately the value for A,B,C... is not fixed and generated dynamically by google finance function (A being the ticker symbol for the stock). how to modify your formula to incorporate that. thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If Col `A` will always have `A,B,C,D,E` in that order:

`=arrayformula(if(A:A<>"",{A:A,QUERY({E:F},"select sum(Col2) where Col2 >100 group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' ",0)*B:B},))`

[image]

If not:

`=arrayformula(if(A:A<>"",QUERY({E:F},"select sum(Col2) where Col2 >100 group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' ",0)*query({A:B},"select Col2 where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0),))`